# Can't access public ip on windows 10

Tags: networking, localhost, dmz

I have a broadband connection in my home and a TENDA router connected.

I have following ip clients:

```
192.168.0.1 ===> Router
192.168.0.100 ===> My Laptop (Windows 10) with IIS, development purpose.
192.168.0.101 ===> My Moto G4 Play (Android OS 6.0)
192.168.0.102 ===> My Computer (Windows 10) No IIS just for surfing and other task.
```

Now I have activated DMZ to 192.168.0.100.
Suppose my public IP is 103.211.52.170

- I can access 103.211.52.170 in my Moto g4 play, it is opening my laptop's localhost.
- I can't access 103.211.52.170 in windows 10 within same network.

Comment: If question have any problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to  configure port forwarding and points to the particular device. Make sure you used the correct ports.

There might be a change in the private IP address in your local network. Make sure you set a static IP or provide a Static DHCP IP Address

Comment: Yes, i have used all of the ports for forwarding